# How to check for specific values in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column that I'm working with that has a number of possible text options in it. The only two I care about are "Bad" or "Good."

I'd like to write a function that results in 1 for "Good," -1 for "Bad," and 0 for anything else.

Is there an easy way to write this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `IF` with `COUNTIF` to test for values. The following will first return true if there are any occurrences of "Good" if that is false it will do the same test for "Bad" returning -1 for true or the empty string.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A31,"Good")>0,1,IF(COUNTIF(A2:A31,"Bad")>0,-1,""))
```

You didn't specify a value if no match is found so I used the empty string. If Good is found this takes precedence over Bad. You could reverse this. If you want to test for both you need to separate the tests.